# Change object var from another script in C#

Tags: c#

i'm stuck trying to change an object var from another script.
I have in script A:

```
public class weapon : MonoBehaviour {

public weapon weaponOn;
private string Name;
private float Damages;
private float FireRate;

public weapon(string name, float damages, float fireRate) {

    this.Name = name;
    this.Damages = damages;
    this.FireRate = fireRate;

}

void Start () {

    weapon weaponOn = new weapon ("Rien", 0, 0);
    Debug.Log (weaponOn.Name);
```

And I'm trying to change the Name of the 'weaponOn' in a script B like :

```
public class buyWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
public static weapon weaponn;

void Start () {

    weaponn = gameObject.GetComponent<weapon> ().weaponOn;
        }

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) {
        weaponn.Name = "New Name"; //Doesn"t contain a definition for Name

        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if it seems easy to you but I'm lost in 'static' var 'public / private' and stuff like that, I'm a newbie in C# so please help.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: The 'gun' im talking about is the weaponOn weapon

Comment: Make weapon have "public string Name { get; set; }". Also looks like you dont need to use statics here (do multiple threads need to share the instance?).

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is `private`. Make it `public`:

```
public string Name;
```